# get input from user and store it in String Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

i write one program that get input from user as "Enter number of students:" then add the student names into it and print it in console. I write one code that run fine but problem is the loop is already ramble one time the code is not properly working i also want to know that how to get inputs using command line argument without **Scanner** and store it in **String Array**

Current Output is like that
[image]

Here is my code please help and i am in learning phrase of Java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringScanner
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //get the input for number of students:
    System.out.println("Enter The number of students:");
    int totalstudents = in.nextInt();

    //store into String array

    String studentname[] = new String[totalstudents];

    for(int i = 0; i < studentname.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println("Enter Student Names: ");
        studentname[i] = in.nextLine();
    }
    for(String names:studentname)
    {
        System.out.println(names);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `the code is not properly working` you have anything new to say?.Note that you have to skip the line after reading `nextInt()` because it doesnot consume the whole line

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Comment: use `in.next()` inside for loop instead of `in.nextLine();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **next():** Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.
>
> **nextLine():** Advances this scanner past the current line and returns
>   the input that was skipped.
>
> Try placing a `scanner.nextLine();` after each `nextInt()` if you intend
>   to ignore the rest of the line.

```
public class StringScanner
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //get the input for number of students:
    System.out.println("Enter The number of students:");
    int totalstudents = in.nextInt();
     in.nextLine();// just to ignore the line
    //store into String array

    String studentname[] = new String[totalstudents];

    for(int i = 0; i < studentname.length;i++)
    {

        System.out.println("Enter Student Names: "+i);
        studentname[i] = in.nextLine();
    }
    for(String names:studentname)
    {
        System.out.println(names);
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array `args[]` 
Need not pass number of students there.

So what ever name you pass on command prompt after **`java <className>`** shall be stored in this array and you can iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

use ArrayList instead of String Array

declare header file

```
      import java.util.ArrayList;
```

change your code

```
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //get the input for number of students:
    System.out.println("Enter The number of students:");
    int totalstudents = in.nextInt();

    //store into arraylist
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < totalstudents;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println("Enter Student Names: ");
        al.add(in.next());
    }
    for(int i=0; i< al.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(al.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: it's not working but the ArrayList is good suggestion just change it to ArrayList <String> = new ArrayList<String> and (al.add(in.next())

Comment: Remove Integer type from ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Add `in.nextLine();` after you assign this `int totalstudents = in.nextInt();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

//get the input for number of students:
System.out.print("Enter The number of students:");
int totalstudents = in.nextInt();

//store into String array

String studentname[] = new String[totalstudents];

for(int i = 0; i < studentname.length;i++)
{
    System.out.print("Enter Student " + i + " Name:");
    studentname[i] = in.nextLine();
}
for(int i = 0; i < studentname.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println(studentname[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some information about how your answer works? A little exposition could help people learn rather than just copy and paste.

Comment: Too add to what @bob0the0mighty had commented Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to get a better understanding of what an answer is. Also, please consider also go through the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: It gets the number of students from the user and stores it in (totalstudents) then creating the array of (studentname) and the length of the array is the number of students entered by the user. 
       In the first loop, the user enter the name of students and stores them in the array of (studentname). In the second loop, the user displaying the names of the students.